# Mutually Exclusive Permissions in J2ME

Tags: java-me, midlet, midp, midp-2.0

What are the other mutually exclusive permissions for a MIDlet aside from "Net Access" and "Auto Invocation"?  Are "Net Access" and "Messaging" not mutually exclusive?

Edit: What about "Messaging" and "Auto Invocation"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stuff like you ask about is covered in MIDP specification addendum: [The Recommended Security Policy for GSM/UMTS Compliant Devices](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr118/MIDP_2.0.1_MR_addendum.pdf). In particular, it explains mutually exclusive permissions as follows:

> ...the Blanket setting for Application Auto Invocation and the Blanket setting for Net Access are **mutually exclusive**. This constraint is to prevent a MIDlet suite from auto-invoking itself, then accessing a chargeable network without the user being aware.

Above document is quite lengthy and complicated. For an easier to understand (though less precise) explanation, consider studying the tutorial article [Understanding MIDP 2.0's Security Architecture](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/index-156128.html):

> This article describes other MIDP 2.0 features that protect users and their devices from malicious software. You'll... learn how to work with MIDP 2.0's security architecture...

Answer (score 0):

Sending and receiving SMS and using GPRS are both possible from the same MIDlet in the same instance.  I'm not aware of any mutually exclusive permissions.